# sharedpreferences issue

Tags: android

I have created a page wherein i receive String and int in EditText, then store in sharedpreferences by clicking save button, however i am not able to make it functional. Specifically data is not stored when i reopen the page data is lost. please help

```
public class Abc extends Activity{
Button one2five, save1;
EditText edtA, edtB, edtC, edtD, edtE, edtF;
String tA;
int tB, tC, tD, tE, tF;
public static String filename = "MySharedString";
SharedPreferences abcPref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.abc);
   one2five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btp1);
   save1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btps1);
   edtA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etA);
   tA = edtA.getText().toString();
   edtB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etB);
   tB = edtB.getInputType();
   edtC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etC);
   tC = edtC.getInputType();
   edtD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etD);
   tD = edtD.getInputType();
   edtE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etE);
   tE = edtE.getInputType();
   edtF = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etF);
   tF = edtF.getInputType();

   one2five.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Intent openg2j = new Intent("com.sport.sport.G2J");

               abcPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Abc.this);
               abcPref.getInt("filename", 0);

               startActivity(openg2j);
       }
   });
   save1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        abcPref= getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = abcPref.edit();
        editor.putString("field1Data", tA);
        editor.putInt("field2Data", tB); 
        editor.putInt("field3Data", tC);
        editor.putInt("field4Data", tD);
        editor.putInt("field5Data", tE);
        editor.commit();
    }
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code it may help you :

```
 public class Abc extends Activity{
Button one2five, save1;
EditText edtA, edtB, edtC, edtD, edtE, edtF;
String tA;
int tB, tC, tD, tE, tF;
public static String filename = "MySharedString";
SharedPreferences abcPref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.abc);
   one2five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btp1);
   save1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btps1);
   edtA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etA);
   tA = edtA.getText().toString();
   edtB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etB);
   tB = edtB..getText().toString();
   edtC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etC);
   tC = edtC..getText().toString();
   edtD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etD);
   tD = edtD..getText().toString();
   edtE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etE);
   tE = edtE..getText().toString();
   edtF = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etF);
   tF = edtF..getText().toString();

// Initialize your sharedpreference here
abcPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("filename", 0); // 0 - for private mode



   one2five.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Intent openg2j = new Intent("com.sport.sport.G2J");
// Here is opening sharedpreference which you have edited in save button
               abcPref = Abc.this.getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
               abcPref.getInt("filename", 0);

               startActivity(openg2j);
       }
   });
   save1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        abcPref=  Abc.this.getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = abcPref.edit();
        editor.putString("field1Data", tA);
        editor.putInt("field2Data", tB); 
        editor.putInt("field3Data", tC);
        editor.putInt("field4Data", tD);
        editor.putInt("field5Data", tE);
        editor.commit();
    }
});
}
}
```

// to get data from SharedPreferences

```
 abcPref=  <<YourActivityName>>.this.getSharedPreferences(filename,0);

    String str1= abcPref.getString("field1Data", "DefaultValue_If_valueIsNull");
    String str2=abcPref.getString("field2Data", "DefaultValue_If_valueIsNull");
    Log.i("Log cat values checking","str1="+str1 +"  str2="+str2);
```

Comment: hello sharp dev. thanks for help; but when i go back to parent acivity and restart this activity data entered is lost. Does this happen due to ---  (filename, 0)---- ??? in shared preferences. Additionaly when i come back to this activity from a G2J activity data remains there.. any comments??

Comment: tB = edtB.getInputType();  instead of this tB = edtB.getText().toString(); same as other lines also. Your issue is something else.

Comment: tB is int type number I want to use this (and other int from other 5 activity) in my final activity and do some calculation. i will be using SharedPreferences getProgramPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("filename", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
String txt1=getProgramPrefs.getString("field1Data");       is it going to work?? does converting it to string will create a problem for calculation??  for example tA+tB=Total

Comment: http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/03/shared-preferences-example-in-android.html  this link will help you. Sharedpreferencs can be acceessed in whole application from any activity.

Comment: one more question -- for G2J activity do i have to use new sharedpreferences name?? (filename was assigned in ABC)..

Comment: Preference name must be same. as your filename="MySharedString"; As simple think as if it is your some file in which you storing data and get it. So in whcih file you store it , you can get it from that file only! :)

Comment: thanks you explained amazingly well can i contact you for future help-

Comment: Sure! I hope you does not need stackoverflow at all!! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36845/discussion-between-sharpdeveloper-and-monika)

Answer (score 0):

- Either use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Abc.this);` for both
  saving and fetching the values or `getSharedPreferences(filename,0);`
- For integer force `EditText` to take only numerics. Use
  `android:inputType="number"`

.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        abcPref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Abc.this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = abcPref.edit();
        editor.putString("field1Data", tA.getText().toString());
        editor.putInt("field2Data", Integer.parseInt(tB.getText().toString())); 
        editor.putInt("field3Data", Integer.parseInt(tC.getText().toString()));
        editor.putInt("field4Data", Integer.parseInt(tD.getText().toString()));
        editor.putInt("field5Data", Integer.parseInt(tE.getText().toString()));
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: hello, tarun i am getting errors in your code:--- Cannot invoke getText() on the primitive type int   ------ and ------ The method getText() is undefined for the type String

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm me, are you populating the data from SharedPref properly to load the data.If please, give a brief. I'm not able to put comment thus.

EDIT:

```
public class Abc extends Activity{
Button one2five, save1;
EditText edtA, edtB, edtC, edtD, edtE, edtF;
String tA;
int tB, tC, tD, tE, tF;
public static String filename = "MySharedString";
SharedPreferences abcPref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.abc);
   one2five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btp1);
   save1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btps1);
   edtA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etA);
   edtB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etB);
   edtC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etC);
   // others..
 }
 public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
   abcPref= getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
   edtA.setText(abdPref.getString("field1Data", null));
   // set others' like


   one2five.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Intent openg2j = new Intent("com.sport.sport.G2J");

               abcPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Abc.this);
               abcPref.getInt("filename", 0);

               startActivity(openg2j);
       }
   });
   save1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tA = edtA.getText().toString();
        tB = edtB.getInputType();
        tC = edtC.getInputType();
        //others..

        abcPref= getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = abcPref.edit();
        editor.putString("field1Data", tA);
        editor.putInt("field2Data", tB); 
        editor.putInt("field3Data", tC);
        editor.putInt("field4Data", tD);
        editor.putInt("field5Data", tE);
        editor.commit();
    }
});
}
}
```

Take a look on this.

Comment: i am populating through user not from the default values

Comment: As you have mentioned your code sharedPref file name `MySharedString`. when you are loading the data via editor.getXXX and set the value to the respective element to display?

Comment: yes display -- more like restore when i restart activity or come back from parent activity

Comment: Please take a look on my Edit. is it helpful to you.